# Update my database after Stripe payment successful

Tags: stripe-payments

I am implementing Stripe on a website for the first time and I'm not sure the right way to do something. After the payment is successful I need to update my database before the client is redirected to the "client's account dashboard", so the dashboard shows the updated information. I thought the right way would be to use webhooks, but if the webhook takes longer to update the database then the redirection, the dashboard will show outdated info.

I found an old post with a similar problem to mine where they said there is no need to use webhooks, as Stripe API calls are synchronous and I can get "the charge object" back which indicates that the payment succeeded. It's a fairly old post so I am not sure if that's the way to go (and also, I can't find information on Stripe Docs on how retrieve the "charge object" once redirected to the "success page")

I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

*Edit: Would polling be a viable way to accomplish this? I can keep the client in the "success page" and use polling to check when the database has been updated, and then redirect.

Comment: You're correct that the modern way to do this is asynchronous. I would suggest rethinking how you're designing this and assume that the webhook response should be successful and the redirect can occur before your database is updated.

Comment: Thanks taintedzodiac. In that case, is it possible to redirect the client once the webhook is done? I mean, I could keep the client in the "success page" until the webhook is done, but I don't think the webhook can trigger the redirect. The only thing I can think of is use polling to check if the database has been updated and then redirect.

Comment: Polling would be the only way to know when any other logic was completed. Usually it's better to not rely on that synchronously, but if you do have to poll, presenting a "processing" message to the user until it's ready is the standard approach.

Comment: Thanks taintedzodiac. That's exactly what I did and it is working quite well. Thanks again!